# Can I get meta "properties" using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm trying to use JS to access data in OpenGraph meta tags.  It works fine with meta tags that have the standard attributes (name="x" content="y"), but for OpenGraph tags, the meta tag reads

```
<meta property="x" content="y">
```

I haven't had any luck accessing the contents of the "property" attribute using JS.  The .name attribute is just empty.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute).

E.g. assuming you have the element in `myMeta`:

```
myMeta.getAttribute('property');
```

There isn't a complete mapping between HTML attributes and DOM properties.   As you've seen, some (possibly invalid) don't have JavaScript properties.  For others, they exist under a different name.  E.g. the `class` attribute becomes `className`.